# "A begs B" or "A begs for B" when we mean that A asks for B

Tags: word-choice, idioms, prepositions

Here's the actual sentence

> "A subjective question begs a subjective answer..."

Something inside my head says it should have been

> "A subjective question begs for a subjective answer..."

Which one is correct in that context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are grammatical, but they mean different things. *A subjective question begs a subjective answer* means that such a question **assumes** a subjective answer. *A subjective question begs for a subjective answer* means it **craves** or **entreats** a subjective answer. However, there are potential hazards in putting *beg* and *question* in the same sentence at all. That is because some readers will insist that *begging the question* should only be used in the philosophical sense of *petitio principii*.  Begging the answer isn’t the same thing as begging the question, but that won’t stop some people. You’d be much safer writing something like *A subjective question prompts a subjective answer.*